# How do I configure Uncrustify to format on save in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, uncrustify

I have installed Uncrustify with Brew on Mac, and installed the extension on VS Code.

I created an uncrustify.cfg and configured some rules.

I would like to use Uncrustify to format the document on save. How can I do this in VS Code?

Comment: does `"editor.formatOnSave": true` not achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I had prettier configured as my code formatter. Once I went to the settings and selected uncrustify, it worked.